# Does the BatchNorm scale the distribution of whole layer (all neurons) or each neuron?

Tags: neural-networks, batch-normalization

I am confused at a very trivial point about the BatchNorm. For illustrations it is a widely used graphics that BatchNorm corrects the distribution of incoming values. To calculate mean, does it average through a batch for each neurons separately or does it average both in 2 dimensions (batch & layer width)?

For example, if I zero some of the neurons after BatchNorm, does this spoil the output distribution or doesn't it since each neuron has its own zero-centered distribution already? (Assuming trainable weight and scale parameter is not used.)

In other words, are the mean and variance unique to a layer, or do we calculate mean & variance for each single neuron in a layer?

Comment: I think it is applied to each neuron separately, am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

We do it for a single neuron.

There is good explanation by Andrej Karpathy lecture:
https://youtu.be/gYpoJMlgyXA?t=3130